# Python regex to extract strings between parenthesis

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to extract values between parenthesis. Let's say I have, the following code:

```
string = "Will Ferrell (Nick Halsey), Rebecca Hall (Samantha), Michael Pena (Frank Garcia)"
pat = re.findall(r'\((.*)\)', string)
```

It returns:

```
[u'Nick Halsey), Rebecca Hall (Samantha), Michael Pena (Frank Garcia']
```

But, I'd like to have:

```
[u'Nick Halsey, Samantha, Frank Garcia']
```

Any idea on how to do so?

Comment: Maybe you want `[u'Nick Halsey', u'Samantha', u'Frank Garcia']`? Then you just need to use `\(([^)]*)\)`

Comment: Escape the parenthesis and make it non-greedy: `re.findall(r'\((.*?)\)', string)`.

Comment: arfff, of course. Thanks